# Incrementing a piece of state causes multiple re-render loop. Assigning state works fine, why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Baasically, I have a REST Api which returns a list of components (sections) from a CMS and their associated data. The UI has a little number next to each section to show the section number, BUT, some sections do not count. For e.g, a career block section. This number is passed as a prop to the rendered section in the form of `:number=""`

So, my function loops through the function and if the component is in the `allowedNumerableSections` array, it will increment, if it doesn't, it will return false and add a increment to the `decrementAmount` state

So basically, say we have 5 sections

```
Section1
Section2
Section3
Section4
Section5
```

`Section3` is NOT in the `allowedNumerableSections` array, so when looping these out, so, if we were to loop out these sections and the passed `:number` prop for each section, it would read:

```
<Section1 number="1" />
<Section2 number="2" />
<Section3 number="false" />
<Section4 number="3" />
<Section5 number="4" />
```

So, we are basically skipping over Section3. So then the UI could read `/01` for Section 1 and `/03` for Section 4.

The problem, is once I add logic to increment state, it loops specifically 608 times for some reason, and the end number ends up saying `/0-201` for example instead of `/04`, or `/0-204` instead of `/01`

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="sections">
    <component
      :is="getSection(section.__component)"
      v-for="(section, index) in sections"
      :key="index"
      :section="section"
      :number="getNumber(section, index)"
      class="section"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SectionStructure",

  components: {
    HeroStyle1: () => import("~/components/hero/HeroStyle1.vue"),
    CommunityBlock: () => import("~/components/sections/CommunityBlock.vue"),
    FiftyFiftyMedia: () => import("~/components/sections/FiftyFiftyMedia.vue"),
    FullscreenGame: () => import("~/components/sections/FullscreenGame.vue"),
    GameRow: () => import("~/components/sections/GameRow.vue"),
    NewsBlock: () => import("~/components/sections/NewsBlock.vue"),
    TitleSideImage: () => import("~/components/sections/TitleSideImage.vue"),
    TwoImagesCta: () => import("~/components/sections/TwoImagesCTA.vue"),
    CareerList: () => import("~/components/sections/CareerList.vue"),
  },
  props: {
    sections: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      allowedNumerableSections: [
        "CommunityBlock",
        "FiftyFiftyMedia",
        "FullscreenGame",
        "GameRow",
        "NewsBlock",
        "TitleSideImage",
        "TwoImagesCta",
      ],
      decrementAmount: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getSection(str) {
      return str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1);
    },
    getNumber(section, index) {
      // If there is any decrementAmount from previous sections,
      // Reduce it from the index of the current section for UI purposes.
      index = index - this.decrementAmount;

      // Converting component names from my-component to MyComponent
      let component = this.getSection(section.__component);
      component = component.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) {
        return g[1].toUpperCase();
      });
      component = component.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + component.slice(1);

      // If the section is a numbered section, return the number in the correct format
      if (this.allowedNumerableSections.includes(component)) {
        return index < 10 ? `/0${index}` : `/${index}`;
      }

      // If I INCREMENT the state, it causes a loop (specifically re-rendering 608 times in this case)
      // and the end number is not correct
      this.decrementAmount++;

      return false;
    },
  },
  computed: {},
};
</script>
```

Although, if I simply assign `decrementAmount` to a value, for e.g just writing `this.decrementAmount = 3` it loops the correct number of times, but now all index's will be reduced by 3 which is what I do not want.

Anybody know why this keeps looping?

Comment: Because getNumber and so decrementAmount++ is executed on each rerender. Don't apply side effects in a template.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each re-render causes `getNumber` to re-calculate, in turn this updates `number` and everything keeps looping. Are you able to assign `number` when you receive the response but before first render? (e.g. on mount, but perhaps better if it's on the response handler)

```
mounted() {
  this.calculateNumber()
},
methods: {
  calculateNumber(apiResult) {
    let decrementAmount = 0
    apiResult.map(section => ({
      ...section,
      number: this.getNumber()
    }))
  }
}
```

As for why you get 608, that's most likely because you reached the recursion limit. How the limit is determined, I can't answer.